# Publish in different domain

Tags: laravel

I have an app that is being used internally in a company domain (ex: http:intranet.company.com), which generates dynamic content like galleries and newsletters. But the company wishes that the galleries and newsletters are viewed in a different domain (ex: newdomainname.com). How or what would be the best way to make it? Should i simply move the public files to the folder hosting of the newdomainname? I cannot move the whole application, only the view galleries and newsletters, because the company wants the management of the galleries be used in the company domain.

P.S. The applications and hosting are in the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering, this change is happening only in the case of **galleries** and **newsletters** (and not js or css), the simplest way of doing it is:

Make a **helper** function to replace old domain with new

```
function newDomainLink($path)
{
  return str_replace('intranet.company.com', 'newdomainname.com', path);
}
```

And use it in your view like

```
<?php echo newDomainLink(url('/gallery/gallery1.jpg')) ?>

// Blade Form
// {{ newDomainLink(url('/gallery/gallery1.jpg')) }}
```

And yes, obviously your need to move your public folder containing **galleries** and **newsletters** files to new domain :)